# Automatic signing is unable to resolve an issue with the "Project" targets entitlement

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to publish a new version of my app to the app store. But during the final stage of archiving I get Automatic signing errors. I have attached an image.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check you profiles and certificates, one of your enabled capabilities like In app purchase , push notification , Inter App audio , Siri kit etc.

Verify and update in Appstore profiles and then clear build and re-archive it. This is the only cause for this type of error.

Make sure that in your App id the above flags should be on.

Most of time it happens when you not configured push notification , In App purchase in you development App ID.

Comment: I checked my push notification and it was yellow and configurable please how do I enable to green?

Comment: If in the App iD of your App its says "Configurable" then you beetter start by creating a new certificate, Push certificate had been expired so it required creating a new push certificate. This invalidated provisioning profile with associated app id. Note you have to update Development and production both push certificates.

Comment: I'm confused now. am I suppose to create a new App ID or certificate because I already have two certificates there?

Comment: Haha, No is your certificate is expired ?

Comment: nTri can I skype you so you help me fix this?